# suspense ssr in react - result renderToPipeableStream not include imported css

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I don't know how to solve the problem with imported css files when rendering on the server. react app.
`

```
renderToPipeableStream(<Html><App assets={assets} /></Html>)
```

`
React components pass to renderToPipeableStream but when server starts it gets all html tags without css files included. I thought renderToPipeableStream would generate css in head or body section. During hydration on client css files are included, compiled with webpack (style-loader,css-loader). How to generate css while rendering on the server side, whether to use webpack there as well, or extract them from  and pass them as assets to html and include them in the head section.

I would like the css to be generated in the head section when rendering on the server using renderToPipeableStream